# Show/hide a div if two numerical characters are inserted into input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I would like to **show/hide** a div if two numerical characters are inserted. I've started with the below but need to incorporate the if two characters are inserted.

```
$('input[name=amount]').keyup(function(){
  if ($(this).val().length)
    $('#yeah').show();
  else
    $('#yeah').hide();
});
```

So; if at least two numerical characters are inserted > `.show();` else `.hide();`

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: you also want the `input` event, not keyup

Comment: do you mean *at least* two numerical characters are inserted? Do you mean this is the condition for execution *all* that code, or do you mean it is the condition for making the "yeah" element visible? Are other characters allowed? If so, should the two digits be at the start, or consecutive or anywhere?

Comment: Yes, if atleast two numerical characters are inserted > show div. Else hide div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex in `.match()` to match numbers in input value and check length of matches.

```
$('input[name=amount]').keyup(function(){
  var match = $(this).val().match(/\d/g);
  if (match != null && match.length > 1)
    $('#yeah').show();
  else
    $('#yeah').hide();
}).keyup();
```

Also you can simplify your code and use `.toggle()`

```
$('input[name=amount]').keyup(function(){
  var match = $(this).val().match(/\d/g);
  $('#yeah').toggle(match != null && match.length > 1);
}).keyup();
```

```js
$('input[name=amount]').keyup(function(){
  var match = $(this).val().match(/\d/g);
  $('#yeah').toggle(match != null && match.length > 1);
}).keyup();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="amount">
<div id="yeah">yeah</div>
```